# SQL Query for multiple SUM function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySql

T1

```
budgetId    fin_year
---------------------
1           17-18
```

T2

```
divisionId  budgetId    totalAmount
-----------------------------------
1           1           10000
2           1           10000
3           1           10000
4           1           0
5           1           100
```

T3

```
workId  divisionId  budgetId    workDescription     workAmount
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       1           1           sssdfs              500
2       1           1           fsfcdsdfgfd         200
```

Now I want **Sum of totalAmount** of T2 table as well as **Sum of total WorkAmount** of T3 for the same budgetId

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sample data: T1(1, 17-18) T2(1, 1, 10000),T2(2,1, 10000), T2(3, 1, 10000), T2(4, 1, 0), T2(4, 1, 100) and T3(1, 1, 1, sfsdfs, 500), T3(2,1,1,fsfcdsdfgfd, 200). Now I want result as total amount is 30100 and amount used is 700

Comment: create table structure and insert data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Not as a comment. Edit the question instead. Don't forget proper formatting. (When you edit, mark the sample data and click `{}`.)

Comment: @ashok, check my answer

Comment: @ashok , my answer is helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
select sum(totalAmount) as total , budgetId , sum(workAmount) as total_used  from T2 
Left Join T3 on T3.budgetId = T2.budgetId
Group By budgetId
```

Hope this query helpful to you , let me know if you fetch any error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you would have if you just do your joins and sum of each column is you will probably overstate your budget amount.  If you have muliple work IDs (T3), then the T2 would get summed for each one.  You would be best to have your T2 and T3 tables pre-summed once by just the budget ID and join on that.  This prevents Cartesian result issues.

```
select
      T1.fin_Year,
      T2Sum.BudgetID,
      T2Sum.TotalByBudget,
      coalesce( T3Sum.WorkAmtPerBudget, 0.0 ) as WorkPerBudget
   from
      T1
         JOIN
         ( select
                 budgetID,
                 sum( totalAmount ) TotalByBudget
              from
                 T2
              group by
                 budgetID ) T2Sum
            on T1.budgetID = T2Sum.budgetID
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select 
                    budgetID,
                    sum( workAmount ) WorkAmtPerBudget
                 from
                    T3
                 group by
                    budgetID ) T3Sum
              on T2Sum.BudgetID = T3Sum.BudgetID
```